# Sending data via post and redirecting user

Tags: redirection, forms

So I made a module that needs to gather some data and redirect user and that data to a payment site.

```
function payment_upload_form($form, &$form_state){


$form = array();    
$form['#action'] = 'www.somepaymantsite.com';
$form['#method'] = 'POST';
$form['CustomerFirstName'] = array(
    '#title' => t('First name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#size' => 25,
);

$form['CustomerLastName'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Last name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#size' => 25,
);
etc....

$form['customersubmit'] = array(
        '#value' => 'Pay now',
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#submit' => array('wspay_submit'),
    );

return $form;

}

function payment_submit($form, &$form_state){
$option = array(
        'ShopID'=>'xzy',
        'ShoppingCartID' => $temp_cid,
        'TotalAmount'=> $amount,
        'Signature' => $signature,
        'ReturnURL' =>'http://some_sitecom',
        'CancelURL' => 'http://some_site.com',
        'ReturnErrorURL' => 'http://some_site.com/1',
        'CustomerFirstName' => $form_state['values']['CustomerFirstName'], 
        'CustomerLastName' => $form_state['values']['CustomerLastName'], 
        ....
        );

$options = array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => drupal_http_build_query($option),
  'timeout' => 15,
  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
);

$response = drupal_http_request('www.somepaymantsite.com', $options);
 $response->redirect_url = 'www.somepaymantsite.com';
```

The problem is that it does not redirect me on the first go, but when I use the same ShoppingCartID it redirects me and I get an error because the ID is the same(it need's to be different every time), but the data is in the URL .
So my question is why does it not redirect the user with the data to the site when he clicks Pay now.

---------------------- EDIT -------------

How can i create a middle page in drupal that has this data and sends it like that, meaning a confirmation page :

```
        <form name=“pay“ action=“https://to.the.shop.something“ method=“POST“>
    <input type=“hidden“ name=“ID“ value=“some_value“>
    <input type=“hidden“ name=“ID2“ value=“some_value“>
 <input type=“hidden“ name=“ID3“ value=“some_value“>
    <input type=“submit“ value=“Pay now“>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your submit function name is wrong , your submit function not called at all, In Drupal if you have form name x then the submit should be x_submit, so in your case the submit function should be

payment_upload_form_submit

Comment: nah that is not the problem i forgot to change the name here :) ...
The problem is that i cant redirect users with the data using POST. Meaning i don't know how :)

Comment: Dont you need to use drupal_goto to perform the redirect ?

Comment: I am trying with drupal_goto($response->redirect_url, array('absolute' => TRUE));  But i am getting 'ReturnErrorURL' from the $option.

Comment: Can some one help don't have no idea how to do this. Can some one just please tell me hot to redirect user with post data to another site ....